# How to handle multiple WSGI applications in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I'm a newbie in Flask and  was wondering how to implement **Flask API** (http://www.flaskapi.org/) along with the main website, for example, main website (/), access API (/api/). In fact, this gives me an Internal Server Error.

Thank you.

```
from flask import Flask, request, url_for
from flask.ext.api import FlaskAPI, status, exceptions

# the all-important app variable:
app = Flask(__name__)
app2 = FlaskAPI(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Oh, Hello Worldaa"

notes = {
    0: 'do the shopping',
    1: 'build the codez',
    2: 'paint the door',
}

def note_repr(key):
    return {
        'url': request.host_url.rstrip('/api/') + url_for('notes_detail', key=key),
        'text': notes[key]
}


@app2.route("/api/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def notes_list():
    """
        List or create notes.
        """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        note = str(request.data.get('text', ''))
        idx = max(notes.keys()) + 1
        notes[idx] = note
        return note_repr(idx), status.HTTP_201_CREATED

    # request.method == 'GET'
    return [note_repr(idx) for idx in sorted(notes.keys())]


@app2.route("/api/<int:key>/", methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def notes_detail(key):
    """
        Retrieve, update or delete note instances.
        """
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        note = str(request.data.get('text', ''))
        notes[key] = note
        return note_repr(key)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        notes.pop(key, None)
        return '', status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT

    # request.method == 'GET'
    if key not in notes:
        raise exceptions.NotFound()
    return note_repr(key)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
    app2.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [Blueprint](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/) in the documentation of Flask.

For example:

```
main = Blueprint(__name__)

@main.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello, World."

api = Blurprint(__name__)

@api.route("/test")
def test():
    return jsonify(dict(test="test")})

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(main)

app.register_blueprint(api, url_prefix="/api")
```

and then, you access index page by http://example.com, access api by http://example.com/api/test